# Are the terms "vector embedding" and "embedding vector" interchangeable?

Tags: embeddings

Googling `"vector embedding"` gives me ~40k results, including from Pinecone, Weaviate, and OpenAI.

Googling `"embedding vector"` gives me ~150k results, including from TensorFlow, Microsoft, and academic sites.

Googling `"vector embedding" vs "embedding vector"` just gives me results mentioning both, not discussions about any difference.

So it doesn't feel like there's a strong consensus that one form is preferred. Is that correct?

Comment: My two cents is that vector embedding vs. embedding vector is a lot less important than stating what is being embedded - i.e. word embeddings vs. sentence embeddings vs. etc. All embeddings that I have worked with have been vectors, but those embeddings may represent very different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are the all the same thing. You can call also just say "embeddings" or "vectors" or more specifically you may talk about a "word embedding" or a "word vector". All of this terminology refers to a vector of numbers that represents something. It's all the same so pick what you like and stick with it.